# Angular 7 Property Binding Techniques

Tags: angular, angular7

I am in the middle of an online course for Angular at a point where the author  discusses property binding.  The author demonstrates three examples of property binding, but does not clearly explain the differences.  Looking for clarification, I've checked several other posts on Stack Overflow but just about every post involves a specific question about the poster's specific situation, none of which helps clarify the more general topic.

Below I've posted an example of three techniques I've seen demonstrated, after which I will ask my questions.  Thanks all in advance for your responses:

Technique 1:

```
<tag [attribute]='binding_value' />
```

Technique 2:

```
<tag attribute={{binding_value}} />

(Note the lack of single quotes - this was intentional 
 and the way demonstrated in the online course.)
```

Technique 3:

```
<tag attribute='blah blah blah...{{binding_value}}' />

...or just assuming we don't need to concatenate 'blah blah blah...', I see
no reason that the following should not also work...

<tag attribute='{{binding_value}}' />

(Note the use of single quotes - this was intentional 
 and was referred to as "interpolation" in the online course.  I provide an
 additional example without string concatenation involved to point out
 that the use or non-use of single quotes as in technique 2 seems arbitrary.)
```

I am having a great deal of trouble understanding when one technique should be used over another.  So I have the following questions:

**Q1:** Based on some of the information in other posts, I want to say that Technique 1 must be used if binding_value is something other than a string - a number or a Boolean value for example.  I could not find absolute confirmation of this assertion though.  Is this correct?

**Q2:** Is technique 2 functionally equivalent to Technique 1, or is there some subtle difference I am missing?

**Q3:** If not attempting "interpolation" (which I assume means concatenation of a string to the binding value based on the context where I've seen the word used), is there ever a reason to put single quotes around the binding value when not using technique 1 or 2?

**Q4:** Are there advantages/disadvantages to one technique over another in certain situations that an experienced developer would tell me "You want to do it this way and here's why..."?

Comment: No point in me attempting to reinvent the wheel... may want to review this blog post as it addresses all of your questions pretty well. https://www.codementor.io/adekunleoyaniyi/interpolation-vs-property-binding-in-angular2-eu1tzbyn4

Comment: I saw this article, but did not trust its content because the author provided what appears to me to be an invalid example for comparison.  He demonstrated interpolation in a comparison, but added single quotes where I believe he should not have.  Not being an expert on the subject though, I am seeking confirmation.  His example:  `<button disabled='{{isDisabled}}'>Try Me</button>
                     </div>` versus what I think should have been demonstrated but am not sure: `<button disabled={{isDisabled}}>Try Me</button>
                     </div>`